# Selenium webdriver C# automation script not working in edge browser

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I have a selenium web driver C# script running successfully in IE browser.
But the same script is not working when I use the MS edge driver.
I have ensured that the OS build number is same as the edge build as suggested [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/). The script launches the URL but fails to find the element with the XPath provided.I am using the latest selenium version: 3.9.1.0 and Edge version:38.14393.2068.0 
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I upgraded my system to new Win10 version and then executed the selenium script with Edge version: 15063. This time the test failed with the following error: System.InvalidOperationException: Element is obscured

Answer (score 0):

I have found that testing with Edge is a real pain because Selenium runs so fast. If the Element isn't found immeditaely then it fails (as it should because it doesn't see it). The only fix I have found is to add a Sleep time before commands that take longer. For example, if the webdriver is directed to a new url, it needs more time to load and find the element. This is a lot of trial and error, and some days it runs slower than others, but this may be what you need to do.

Comment: thanks for your input. I will try with timeout. Just wanted to know if you faced the same exception: "System.InvalidOperationException: Element is obscured"